# Latex markup removal script (delcmdchanges.bash) not working

Tags: changes, bash

I have used `changes` package in my latex source code. To accept changes I can use `final` in tex file in order to remove tags in the output (PDF). If I need to remove markup in latex source,[delcmdchanges.bash](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/changes?lang=en)  script is avaliable but the output is alike input, It doesn't remove markup in the latex.

I tried, `sudo sh delcmdchanges.bash input.tex output.tex`

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}
\centerline{\sc \large A Simple Sample \LaTeX\ File}
\vspace{.5pc}
\centerline{\sc Stupid Stuff I Wish Someone Had Told Me Four Years Ago}
\centerline{\it (Read the .tex file along with this or it won't 
            make much sense)}
\vspace{2pc}
The first thing to realize about \LaTeX\ is that it is not ``WYSIWYG''. 
In other words, it isn't a \added{some text} word processor; 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the script into the same folder where your *.tex files resides. Make the script executable. Don't use sudo, simply open a terminal, navigate into that folder and try:

```
sh ./delcmdchanges.bash -i input.tex output.tex
```

or

```
./delcmdchanges.bash -i input.tex output.tex
```

Comment: I tried it in the same folder where latex file resides but same output. Actually `-i` option doesn't work it dint prompt the options to select whether to accept or reject markup.

Comment: Did you make the script executable? What exactly was the output, please just copy it as a comment here.