# Removing all markup automatically changes package

Tags: scripts, changes, bash

I have looked around and found no answer to this question. 
I am using the `changes` package, and I need to remove all markup from the source file. There's [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/264114/90297) about using the [delcmdchanges.bash](https://sourceforge.net/projects/changes/files/), but sadly it goes unanswered.

My questions are these: why is the script not working, and is there a way to make it work ? Is there another script ? (hopefully one that can be used on a windows machine as well)

Some background - I am using a lubuntu 16.04 machine.

I am trying to remove the markup from the following file to no avail:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changes} %I could use [final] to hide the markup from the PDF, but I need the ``evidence'' removed from the source

\begin{document}
 Some text \added{some added text}, and some \replaced{replaced}{replactd} text. \deleted{also, some deleted.}
\end{document}
```

I placed the script in the same folder as input.tex, made the script executable and used

```
sh ./delcmdchanges.bash -i input.tex output.tex
```

I get no error, no query as to found markup, and the output file contents is identical to the input.

Comment: For windows I suggest cygwin (as a general rule, but it would do the trick here too)

Comment: That's a shell for running bash in windows environment, I meant whether there was something more general like a python script

Comment: The heavy lifting is done by awk.  You could [install that on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows) but you'd still need to wrap the calls to awk in a batch file.  But seriously if you're used to *nix, being able to run proper shell scripts on windows is a feature worth having

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this problem does not exist in newer versions of the package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the command

```
awk -W version
```

It probably tells you something like `mawk 1.3.3`. `mawk` is a particular implementation of `awk`, which in this version has the bug (missing feature?) that it does not support Posix character classes. The script `delcmdchanges.bash` uses the character class `[:space:]`, which is not interpreted correctly.

Your options are:

- Upgrade to `mawk` 1.3.4. Though available since quite some time, it didn't yet make it into several Linux distributions (like Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 as well as all current (=Nov 2016) Debian releases, including sid).
- Install another implementation of `awk`, like `gawk`. If it is not automatically made the default after installation (meaning that `awk` now invokes `gawk`), replace `awk` by `gawk` in the script.
- Alternatively, edit the script and replace all occurrences of

  ```
  [[:space:]]
  ```

  by

  ```
  [ \t\r\n\v\f]
  ```

  (the backslashes are to be taken literally, so a string of 11 characters is replaced by a string of 13 characters).

Comment: The second alternative worked very well, thank you. I tried the third first and it did not work. I did not fancy the first as the repository version is 1.3.3. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @EladDen Can you check whether you have really replaced all 19 occurrences of `[[:space:]]` by `[ \t\r\n\v\f]` (note that the second character of the second string is a space character), with the replacement string amounting to 13 characters? I have tested it on Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10, and it works in both cases.

Comment: I might have made a mistake copying the new string. I tried it again, (also replacing awk with mawk, since I have gawk installed now) and it seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of the package contain a new script written in python. It can be used by running `python pyMergeChanges.py [-arh] <Input File> <Output File>` from the script folder.

Therefore, I would recommend a person that comes across the problem with the bash file to update the package or download the new script.

For more info see the package documentation.

Comment: A package is mentioned but not the source of this "package", where can I get `pyMergeChanges.py`?  It's not part of https://github.com/google-research/arxiv-latex-cleaner/tree/main at least as far as I could see.

Comment: Ahh, I see now, `pyMergeChanges.py` is part of the _changes_ latex package https://changes.sourceforge.net/.  You need to download the zip file and from it extract the python script.

Comment: One hassle is that the output is written as utf-8 file which overleaf treats as binary file (at least in my hands). I'm experienced python coder so I replaced the codecs.open(FILE,mode=XX,encoding='utf-8') with simple python open(FILE,mode=XX) and ran script to simply write ASCII 8 bit files. It seems to work although I'm no expert in character encodings.  Others might try looking at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171832/converting-a-utf-8-file-to-ascii-best-effort in case they want to just convert and hope.  (Our latex is written in pure ASCII)

Comment: `pyMergeChanges.py` is not perfect, e.g. it cannot deal with \added{ for multiline paragraph adds. And it mangled one \cref command causing latex build to break. Expect some manual editing after running it.